# Tweepy: Check if a user is following me

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have the following code, where I'm trying to unfollow anyone who isn't following me. I'm currently just  seeing if a username is in the followers list, and if not, unfollowing them.

```
followers = []
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
    followers.append(follower.screen_name)

for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends).items():
    if friend.screen_name in followers:
        continue
    else:
        api.destroy_friendship(friend.screen_name)
```

It's somewhat tedious, so I'd like to make it shorter. I think I'm supposed to use either `api.show_friendships` or `api.lookup_friendships`, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
my_screen_name = api.me().screen_name
    status = api.show_friendship(source_screen_name = friend.screen_name, target_screen_name = my_screen_name)
    if status[0].following:
        print(f'{friend.screen_name} follows {my_screen_name}.')
    else:
        api.destroy_friendship(friend.screen_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lookup_friendships` to confirm who is following you

```
    screen_names = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

    ret = api.lookup_friendships(screen_names = screen_names)
    for rel in ret:
        # name:user1 isFollowedBy? False
        print(f'name:{rel.screen_name} isFollowedBy? {rel.is_followed_by} ')
```

The output is the a list of `Relationship` objects where you can see who is a follower (see example above) and who you are following